# How do I modify the output directory of jar generated by sbt assembly

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I am using sbt-assembly to create an executable jar.

I was wondering, how do I modify the output directory of jar generated by `sbt assembly`?

By default, the generated jar is in `/path/target/scala-2.11/`. I want to change this to not include the scala version, that is, have the generated jar be in `/path/target/` instead.

How to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change `target in assembly` setting as follows:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
      organization := "com.example"
    )),
    name := "hello-world",
    target in assembly := target.value
  )
```

Comment: I don't understand. What will be the output directory in your example?
EDIT:Oh okay, I got it.  Settings `target in assembly := file("outputdir")`